# Why do I get "undefined method `encoding' "?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

Why do I get "undefined method `encoding' "?
How can I fix this?

**Error Message**

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `encoding' for #<Array:0x000000218f61e8>):
 app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:255:in `deliver'
```

**messages_controller.rb**

```
# coding: UTF-8

class MessagesController < ApplicationController

    deliver
        users = User.confirmed.order("created_at ASC")

        @users_emails = []          
        users.each do |user|
            @users_emails += [user.email]
        end

        subject = params[:messages][:subject] 
        body = params[:messages][:body]

        CallMailer.call_email(@users_emails, subject, body).deliver  <= This is line 255  
    end

end
```

**mailers/call_mailer.rb**

```
# coding: UTF-8

class CallMailer < ActionMailer::Base

    default :from => "dont-reply@example.com"

    def call_email(users_emails, mesesage_subject, mesesage_body)
        @users_emails = users_emails
        @mesesage_subject = mesesage_subject
        @mesesage_body = mesesage_body
        mail(
            :bcc => @users_emails,
            :subject => @mesesage_subject,
            :body => @mesesage_body) do |format|
            format.html
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Probably this could help https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/417

Comment: @Debadatt probably that's it! could you show me how to fix my code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found you are getting the right array for bcc probably you have some mistypes email address.

***When an e-mail address contains a dot before the @, for example test.@test.com, and is submitted as part of an Array you get an undefined method `encoding' for Array. The bug only appears in Ruby 1.9 and only if the address is submitted as an array.***

try this

```
def call_email(users_emails, mesesage_subject, mesesage_body)
        @users_emails = users_emails
        @mesesage_subject = mesesage_subject
        @mesesage_body = mesesage_body
        mail(
            :bcc => @users_emails.join(','),
            :subject => @mesesage_subject,
            :body => @mesesage_body) do |format|
            format.html
        end
    end
```

Comment: Thanks! this was it! Critical answer!

Comment: It not only happends on BCC or when having . before @. To me it happend all the time. I solved this 

driver_managers_team: %w(mail1@example.co mail2@example.co).join(',')

Answer (score 3):

In your `CallMailer` you as because :bcc only use string not array

so can you do

```
@user_emails.each do |email|     
  mail(
        :bcc => email,
        :subject => @mesesage_subject,
        :body => @mesesage_body) do |format|
        format.html
    end 
end
```

thanks

Comment: Thanks! Where should it be?

Comment: what about replacing `:bcc => @users_emails` with `:bcc => [@users_emails]` ?

Comment: @user_emails.each do |email|

Comment: are you sure about this part? `,...`

Comment: Why do you make it work separately? Isn't your way for `:to`? I thought that you can set whole at once if it's array and setting as bcc.

Comment: If there were 500 users. Your transaction will be proceeded for 500 times.

Comment: Please see Rajarshi Post it was a better way

Answer (score 2):

Actuallly bcc will look like this

```
 mail(:to => "rails@example.com" ,  :subject => "Example Rails"
 :bcc => ["bcc@rails.com", "Rails Group <railsgroup@example.com>"] ,
 :cc => "other@example.com" )
```

so you can do one thing make the bcc
        `bcc = []`
        `@user_emails.each do |email|`
         `bcc << email + ","`
        `end`

```
    mail(:to => "rails@example.com",:subject => "Example Rails", :bcc => bcc, :cc => "other@example.com" )
```

Thanks

Comment: so what about replacing :bcc => @users_emails with :bcc => [@users_emails] ?